# show that the series converges absolutely and uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

[image]
I do not understand why there is some $C>0$ such that for all integers $n$ and $x$ in the interval we have $|1-x^2/n^2|\geq C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[a,b]$ be that interval and consider the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[a,b]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\left|1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right|.\end{array}$$Then, since there are no integers in $[a,b]$, you always have $f(x)>0$. So, $f$ has a minimum $C>0$, and then$$(\forall x\in[a,b]):\left|1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right|\geqslant C.$$

Comment: Thank you. That $f$ takes a minimum is due to the fact that $[a,b]$ is compact?

Comment: Yes, although the fact that a continuous function from an interval $[a,b]$ into $\Bbb R$ always has a minimum and a maximum is usually proved before the introduction of the concept of compact space.